# Chrome extension which allows custom javascript code to run after page load

Tags: javascript, chrome

I'm looking to see if anyone knows of a Chrome extension where you can run saved Javascript code (or run a .js file) for a website after it loads.

So it would be the equivalent to opening up and running some code in the Developer Tools console after the page loads. I'd like something which would automate this process.

Comment: Try [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/). By default it cannot access filesystem resources, though. Enable it inside the config panel. You still would have to convert your snippets / JS ifles into a specific userscripts format (.user.js), stored "inside Tampermonkey".

Comment: Tampermonkey looks promising!